# Uploading files one by one using Webclient.UploadFileAsync

Tags: c#

I'm sending multiple files to my wrapper which sends files to ftp.I have to get the progress of the upload, so i have to use asycn method for uploading.The problem is, how can i call the uploader one by one, but also get the progress report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution if you want to wait for each file:

```
class FileUploader
{
    private readonly Uri _destination;

    public FileUploader(Uri destination)
    {
        _destination = destination;
    }

    public void UploadFiles(IEnumerable<string> fileNames)
    {
        foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
        {
            UploadFile(fileName);
        }
    }

    private void UploadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.UploadProgressChanged += UploadProgressChangedHandler;
            client.UploadFileCompleted += (sender, args) => UploadCompletedHandler(fileName, tcs, args);
            client.UploadFileAsync(_destination, fileName);
            tcs.Task.Wait();
        }
    }

    private void UploadCompletedHandler(string fileName, TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        }
    }

    private void UploadProgressChangedHandler(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle progress, e.g.
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to subscribe to the `UploadProgressChanged` event:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.UploadProgressChanged += (s, e) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage);
client.UploadFileAsync(new Uri("ftp://server/directory"), @"C:\temp\file.txt");
client.UploadFileCompleted += (s, e) => Task.Factory.StartNew(client.Dispose);
```

Comment: Cheers,normally i do,however if I upload using "client.UploadFile", event handlers dont catch the progress changed event...

Comment: you can't get progress update while running sync. You have to use async, as you originally stated

Comment: i know i can not :) Actually the question is, how can i upload files one by one using an async job?

Comment: just put the above code in a method and call it for each file. If you want to wait for each one to finish uploading before starting, you could use a TaskCompletionSource